# How to get keyword by tcm id from GraphQL

Tags: taxonomy, graphql, brokerquery

We are currently rewriting some old .net code that is using the old in process api to retrieve published data from broker. We are now trying to rewrite this to GraphQL. We stumble into a lot of things as we are quite new to GraphQL.

One very simple example that we stumble with is how to retrieve a keyword from its tcm id. Any suggestions how to solve things like this?

Old code:
TaxonomyFactory taxonomyFactory = new TaxonomyFactory();
var keyword = taxonomyFactory.GetTaxonomyKeyword(keywordTcmId.ToString());

In GraphQL we can't find a way to retrieve a keyword without also specifying its category, alternativly retrieving all categories and keywords and after that process the result.
Are we missing something?

Best regards
Fredrik